# Install WordPress Site Inside a Subdirectory of Another WordPress Instance on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, hosting, web-hosting

I installed an instance of WordPress (Click to Deploy) on Google Compute Engine, but I would like to install another instance in a subdirectory of that, such as www.mywebsite.com/anotherwebsite. Is there a way to create an instance inside of another? Also, I have FTP access so I could install WordPress myself in the subdirectory but I need a database to connect to. Is there a way to just create a MyQL database without WordPress? Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I installed an instance of WordPress (Click to Deploy) on Google
>   Compute Engine, but I would like to install another instance in a
>   subdirectory of that, such as www.mywebsite.com/anotherwebsite. Is
>   there a way to create an instance inside of another?

Provided that you do not pick a WordPress directory name, WordPress won't even know that another WordPress installation is installed. However, you will need to set up Apache to correctly handle the directories for each VirtualHost. If you plan to run both WordPress installations on the same IP/port you will have work to do to correctly setup httpd.conf

> Is there a way to just create a MySQL database without WordPress? Any
>   suggestions welcome.

Yes. Just install the MySQL CLI (mysql). You can connect to the MySQL server and create a new database named differently than the first WordPress installation.

I recommend creating a new MySQL user for the second WordPress installation. Then edit wp-config.php and set up the correct parameters for the home directory location, server name, port, database, etc.

Unless you understand WordPress well, have lots of time to configure and test everything, understand how to dual host with Apache, why do this? Just create another VM and install WordPress on its own installation. Additional options are App Engine (Standard and Flexible) and Kubernetes.